# Motorola HS805 Driver for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, wireless-headset

I have been using my this headset device Motorola HS805 with my phone and with my laptop running windows XP sp2. But as now i have upgraded my OS to windows 7, i tried to connect and use headset with my laptop again. It connects to my device but proper driver is not installed for it. Does anyone know where can i find HS805 driver for windows 7?